# How to auto-document Python code containing Fortran shared library (F2PY)

Tags: python, fortran, doxygen, python-sphinx, f2py

I've written a significant amount of Python code, which calls Fortran shared library files (created using F2PY). I want to document both my Python and Fortran codes automatically.

I tried

1. Doxygen, and
2. Sphinx

The problem with Doxygen (I'm new to Doxygen) is that it does not seem to have a native support for Python 2.7 (I might be wrong here as the Doxygen webpage seems to say it does support Python) the way Sphinx has. BUT, it works to a certain extent.

The problem with Sphinx (I've some prior experience with Sphinx) is that the included compiled Fortran shared libraries seem to flip Sphinx's Makefile (make html) giving errors like this:

> import getElemData_fortran
>
> ImportError: 
>   dlopen(getElemData_fortran.so, 2): no suitable image found.
>
> Did find: getElemData_fortran.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00

Please suggest how I may coerce Sphinx to auto-document my Python code containing compiled Fortran libraries.

Comment: Which version of doxygen did you use? What were the results. Please show a small example with Doxyfile that you tried.